# Get Python Array Key Text

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.8.5 on Ubuntu & can't figure out how to get the key for from this data:

`{'2020-10-31': {'intangibleAssets': 831000000, 'capitalSurplus': 5311000000, 'totalLiab': 4754000000, 'totalStockholderEquity': 4873000000, 'otherCurrentLiab': 496000000, 'totalAssets': 9627000000, 'commonStock': 3000000, 'otherCurrentAssets': 127000000, 'retainedEarnings': 81000000, 'otherLiab': 876000000, 'goodWill': 3602000000, 'treasuryStock': -522000000, 'otherAssets': 601000000, 'cash': 1441000000, 'totalCurrentLiabilities': 1467000000, 'deferredLongTermAssetCharges': 380000000, 'otherStockholderEquity': -522000000, 'propertyPlantEquipment': 1020000000, 'totalCurrentAssets': 3415000000, 'longTermInvestments': 158000000, 'netTangibleAssets': 440000000, 'netReceivables': 1127000000, 'longTermDebt': 2284000000, 'inventory': 720000000, 'accountsPayable': 354000000}}`

The above data is the output from:

```
print(data_input)
```

I can print the key to standard output like this:

```
my_array = data_input[0]

print(*list(my_array))
```

The above code gives the out put that I need:

```
2020-10-31
```

But I need that in a variable. So when I try to put that into a variable it doesn't work:

```
my_array = data_input[0]

my_key = print(*list(my_array))
```

It simply prints it to the standard output.

What I want to do is have this:

```
print(my_key)
```

With the output being:

```
2020-10-31
```

I can't figure this out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list containing the keys of a dictionary  by calling its `keys()` method:

```py
dic = {"key1": "value1, "key2: "value2"}
print(dic.keys())
print(dic.keys()[0])
my_key = dic.keys()[0]
print(my_key)
```

Comment: When I try: `print(dic.keys())` it shows me the key, but the output is this: `dict_keys(['2020-10-31'])` and I need the output to be `2020-10-31`. But you've pointed me in the right direction. If I use this, it give me the right output. `print(list(dict.keys())[0])`.